# Mapping Array Data to Struct with Bitfields

Tags: arrays, struct, mapping, field, bit

I have a 2-D integer array (8x8) where each "row" contains a received message. I am interested in mapping the elements of this array, incomingMessageBuffers[1][0:7], into a struct with defined bitfields which may turn out to be faster than using the mask and shift method. I know that bitfield ordering is compiler-dependent but regardless I would like to understand why I am seeing the observed behavior as I think it is unrelated to this fact.

The memory I am trying to map into MYSTRUCT

```
 - incomingMessageBuffer [1][0:7]  
    0. 0x1544 
    1. 0x0000 
    2. 0x0008 
    3. 0x3400 
    4. 0x0012 
    5. 0x8100 
    6. 0x0000 
    7. 0x0000
```

MYSTRUCT definition:

```
struct MYSTRUCT{
   unsigned int PACKET0:16;
   unsigned int PACKET1:16;
   unsigned int PACKET2:16;

   unsigned char PACKET3_LOW:8;
   unsigned int MYINTEGER:16;
   unsigned char PACKET4_HIGH:8;

   unsigned char PACKET5_LOW:8;
   unsigned char MYBIT:1;
   unsigned char EXTRABITS:3;
   unsigned char MYNIBBLE:4;

   unsigned int PACKET6:16;
   unsigned int PACKET7:16; }
```

My code for the mapping and examples of desired result:

```
volatile struct MYSTRUCT *Message           
Message = &incomingMessageBuffer[1][0];     

myInteger = (Message->MYINTEGER);           
myBit = (Message->MYBIT);       
myNibble = (Message->MYNIBBLE);

Expected values:
myInteger = 0x1234
myBit = 0x01;
myNibble = 0x08;
```

Instead, this maps to PACKET0,1 and 2 correctly but the following member assignments are incorrect. From my understanding of the convention for this type of definition...

```
struct
{
    type [member_name] : width ;
};
```

type is defining the member_name type (i.e. PACKET6, MYBIT, etc.) where if the type size is greater than the width the extra upper bits in member_name will be padded  with zeros. I guess this is incorrect because I do not see the expected values being assigned unless I define my structure as such:

```
struct MYSTRUCT_2{
    unsigned int PACKET0:16;
    unsigned int PACKET1:16;
    unsigned int PACKET2:16;

    unsigned char PACKET3_LOW:8;
    unsigned long int MYINTEGER:16; //Notice long int here
    unsigned char PACKET4_HIGH:8;

    unsigned char PACKET5_LOW:8;
    unsigned char MYBIT:1;
    unsigned char EXTRABITS:3;
    unsigned char MYNIBBLE:4;

    unsigned int PACKET6:16;
    unsigned int PACKET7:16;
}
```

and then assign my variables using masking of the structure members:

```
volatile struct MYSTRUCT *Message           
Message = &incomingMessageBuffer            

myInteger = (Message->MYINTEGER)&0xFFFF         
myBit = (Message->MYBIT)&0x01           
myNibble = (Message->MYNIBBLE)&0x0F
```

So why does declaring MYINTEGER as an unsigned **long** int cause correct assignment as per the bit mapping if it is just defining the size of MYINTEGER?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue might be due to the integer definitions in my first structure being misaligned. Where alignment would entail the integer's first bit being defined on a multiple of 16.

Such that...

```
struct MYSTRUCT{
   unsigned int PACKET0:16;
   unsigned int PACKET1:16;
   unsigned int PACKET2:16;

   unsigned char PACKET3_LOW:8;   
   unsigned char PACKET4_HIGH:8;
   unsigned int MYINTEGER:16;

   unsigned char PACKET5_LOW:8;
   unsigned char MYBIT:1;
   unsigned char EXTRABITS:3;
   unsigned char MYNIBBLE:4;

   unsigned int PACKET6:16;
   unsigned int PACKET7:16; }
```

...works since MYINTEGER comes after two char definitions each mapping to 8 bits in the struct. Yet using this same logic I don't understand why declaring it as a long int would fix the issue.